# How to include a custom header using AWS SDK with SQS Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using the AWS SDK SQS (with Nodejs) behind a router, to get through the router I need to include a custom header in the REQUEST.

I've seen this documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#build-event) that talks about the *.on ('build')* event in REQUEST:

```
var req = s3.putObject(params);
req.on('build', function() {
    req.httpRequest.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'value';
});
req.send(function(err, data) { ... });
```

However, using the *SQS service* is not working, no error has been thrown and the custom header is not included in the REQUEST.

Is it possible include a custom header using AWS SDK with *SQS service* ?
How make to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

After help, I was able to send messages to the queue with a custom header, below the sample code:

```
var sqs = new aws.SQS({http_wire_trace: true});

var params = {
    MessageBody: 'Hello world!',
    QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    DelaySeconds: 0
};

var req = sqs.sendMessage(params);

req.on('build', () => {
    req.httpRequest.headers['Custom-Header'] = 'bar';
});

req.on('success', (resp) => {
    console.log(resp.request.httpRequest.headers)
    });

req.send();
```